# Azure AD service app registration automatically allowed for clients without approval

Tags: entra-id, azure-app-services

I have an Azure Web App Service that will be used in a service-to-service environment. I want that this service to use the Azure AD app registration for authentication. This service will due to it's implementation only use client credentials grant type for the authentication process.

I expect that since my client app registration doesn't have any API permissions configured against my service app registration that the authentication should fail, but it doesn't; it returns a valid access token with my service app registration `Application ID URI` as audience that can be used to access my Azure App Service.

So, why does this happen? I expect that an app registration isn't available until there is an approved API permission configured for my client registration, but this isn't the case.

This is what I have done:

I have created an app registration the following way to make this work:

- Made a app registration manually in Azure AD with
- `Supported account types` set to `Accounts in this organizational directory only`
- Added an `Application ID URI`
- Added a client secret (used by the Azure App Service configuration)
- Created an App role (since this is a requirement to be able to use client credentials grant type as far as I have understood)

This app registration is then connected to the Web App service using the `Authentication / Authorization` configuration on the App Service using advanced configuration (not that this is relevant for this issue).

I also created a another app registration that identifies my client service. This service has **not** been configured to access the service app registration. I then use this client service credentials to authenticate against my Azure AD using client credentials grant type with the service `Application ID URI` as scope.

I know that I can limit the access in my code by checking the role, but that's not the issue here, I am wondering why it returns a valid access token at all with my service `Application ID URI` as audience.

NOTE: I have found that if I go to enterprise applications and set `User assignment required?` to Yes, it will return 400, but is there any way to have this as default for all new app registrations, to ease the app registration?